Importing , parsing and replacing XML files using Python
I have 2 XML files, file number one and file number 2.
In python I want to create a file number 3 by calling call file number one, and inside file number one , file number two is called like this ...
File number 2 it's this : technology.xml
I must say that the file number one is in a different folder than file number 2.
In the new file I want where it calls the technology to replace it entirely with file number 2.
It imports the file, parses with , but it does not replace with what I want.
This is the python code:

def __init__(self, client_name):
self.client_name = client_name
self.root = None

def parse_master(self, path):
master_root = None
try:
tree = ET.parse(path)
master_root = tree.getroot()
except FileNotFoundError:
print(f"Error loading Master: {path}")
return master_root

def read_client_config(self):
\# Parse client XML file
file = f'Clients\\{self.client_name}\_new.xml'
tree = ET.parse(file)
self.root = tree.getroot()

    # Get all master XML files
    directory = "Master"
    files = glob.glob(f"{directory}/*.xml")
    
    # Parse each master XML file
    for path in files:
    
        print(f"Parsing master file: {path}")
    
        # Parse master file
        master_root = self.parse_master(path)
    
        if master_root is not None:
            for master in self.root.findall(".\\Master"):
    
                source = master.get("source")
                if source == os.path.basename(path):
    
                    # find parent of master element
                    parent = None
                    for elem in self.root.iter():
                        for child in elem:
                            if child is master:
                                parent = elem
                                break
                        if parent is not None:
                            break
    
                    # remove namespace prefix from children elements
                    for child in master_root:
                        ET.register_namespace('', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
                        child.tag = child.tag.partition('}')[2]
    
                    # replace master element with the children of the master root
                    if parent is not None:
                        try:
                            index = parent.index(master)
                            parent.remove(master)
                            for child in [master_root] + list(master_root):
                                parent.insert(index, copy.deepcopy(child))
                                index += 1
                        except AttributeError:
                            pass
                    break

def get_master_path(self, source):

    if not source:
      print("Invalid source")
      return None
    
        # The path to the master directory containing the master XML files.
    master_dir = r'C:\Master'  
    master_path = os.path.join(master_dir, source)
    print(f"Master path: {master_path}")
    
    # Optional normalization
    master_path = os.path.abspath(master_path)
    
    return master_path

def write_config(self):
temp_dir = 'temp'
if not os.path.exists(temp_dir):
os.mkdir(temp_dir)

        output_file = os.path.join(temp_dir, f'{self.client_name}_config.xml')  
        tree = ET.ElementTree(self.root)
        tree.write(output_file)

import unittest
from Config import Config
import os

class TestConfig(unittest.TestCase):

def test_read_client_config(self):
config = Config('Ibersol')
config.read_client_config()

    self.assertEqual(config.client_name, 'client')
    self.assertEqual(config.root.tag, 'audit')
    # Add more assertions

def test_write_client_config(self):
config = Config("client")
config.read_client_config()

        temp_dir = "temp"
        output_file = os.path.join(temp_dir, "client_config.xml")
    
        config.write_config()
    if name == 'main': unittest.main()

This is a snippet of the XML code that I want replicated and replaced in the master
</file\>

    <master source="technology.xml">
        <parameter id="_users_" value="technology.users" source="local" />
    </master>
    
</input>

I want to replicate the file number one as a number 3 but in the parts where is suppose to call the master , I want it replaced with the master itself which is file number 2.


xpath is bad self.root.findall(".\\Master") it should be .//master 2) elements can obtain their parent with element.getparent() 3) questions are almost required to provide a [mcve]

